# How to extract value from xml clob with identical tags using FOR LOOP in PL/SQL

Tags: xml, plsql

In most cases I deal with simple xml CLOBs with the following structure:

```
<SuggestResponse>
  <suggestions>
    <value>ПАО "Cбербанк"</value>
    ....
    ....
  </suggestions>
</SuggestResponse>
```

I can easily extract values and then compare them to any variables I have:

```
IF variable = xmltype(xmlclob.extract('SuggestResponse/suggestions/value/text()').getstringval() THEN 
.....
END IF;
```

But sometimes I get XML CLOBs with the different structure:

```
<SuggestResponse>
  <suggestions>
    <value>ПАО "Cбербанк"</value>
    ....
    ....
  </suggestions>
  <suggestions>
    <value>ПАО Банк «ФК Открытие»</value>
    ....
    ....
  </suggestions>
</SuggestResponse>
```

There are 2 or more  tags and I don't know how to check each of them using FOR LOOP. How to point to FOR LOOP which `<suggestions>` is currently in use (first, second...).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would avoid the use of the deprecated extract (and extractvalue) and use XMLTABLE to query the contents of the xml document. This will be faster than looping over the same document to extract the contents individually, since it means the xml doc will only need to be read once.

You can do this like so:

```
DECLARE
  v_xml XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<SuggestResponse>
  <suggestions>
    <value>fred</value>
    <node2>abc</node2>
    <node3>1</node3>
  </suggestions>
  <suggestions>
    <value>bob</value>
    <node2>def</node2>
  </suggestions>
</SuggestResponse>');
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT *
              FROM   XMLTABLE('/SuggestResponse/suggestions' PASSING v_xml
                              COLUMNS val varchar2(100) PATH 'value',
                                      node2 VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'node2',
                                      node3 NUMBER PATH 'node3'))
  LOOP
    IF rec.node2 = 'abc'
    THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(rec.val||': hurrah!');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line(rec.val||': boo!');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

fred: hurrah!
bob: boo!
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing solution! I'm going to rewrite a lot of my code. Because everytime I use getstringval() I make http request which returns heavy XML. That is so unefficient!